# Why the filter method is not working when filtering an array of objects requested from an API (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, filter, methods, include, fetch-api

I have been practicing some coding after some break. I'm trying to filter an array of objects from an api and creating a function the which will return me every word from the title of the fetch I'm making the request.

However, when I want to do the filter it shows that filter method is not recognized, and I don't know if its affected if you are filtering an array that you called from an api.

This is the code.

```
function titles(word){
    let sentence
    let array = []
    let api = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts'
    let data = fetch(api)
    let response = data.then(res => res.json()).then(data => data.map((e) => { e.title}))
    array = array.concat(response)
    sentence = Promise.all(array.flat()).then(results => results.flat())
  const people = sentence.filter(e => e.title.includes(word))
    return people
}
```

However, returns an error message (see image)

But when I do the same on an array of objects the filter works well.

I appreciate any help, feedback and code improvement. Thanks in advance!

[image: error message]

Comment: `sentence` is a promise, not an array. Put the `filter` call inside a `.then()` call, just like you did with all the `map` and `flat` calls

Comment: `let array = []; …; array = array.concat(response); Promise.all(array.flat()).then(results => results.flat())` is pretty pointless. You have an array containing a single promise, and with `Promise.all`, a promise for an array containing a single result. Just use only `response.then(result => …)`

Comment: please add the error message in your question instead of pasting an image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here we have to take a look at the part where you are trying to extract the `data`. Adding a proper way to fetch by converting it to `JSON` will help. using `data.json()`   after which you can `filter`. Conforming with your code flow, now after this, you can use the `filter` option.

You can find working code [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=12&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#code/IYZwngdgxgBAZgV2gFwJYHsIzcgNgUxAAoB3dAJwBMBKGAbwCgYYpMRkYR8Jlup8YAXhgBtALoBuJizYdgAB1RCYAIgAWyZPJAAuAPR6AViEzzcwfmvS5K%20cgDpkYRa1v3WAWz3z07ECqlmVgh2GEpgZGBlYBJgVA44fGQoNSIFVGpAmRCOckIfEIFhGLiOcMj7Y0wiTOlg0JwCEGU8kAKuew8FIiI6bHiCGABfWkEAPn68fFrmLh4%20fHt5BBBU%203XGwhns0Pl8dDMizm5eaEW4VFxech7N0YnN%201QIWwAPAHk4UgoaGAmAWgAjNs8sgEOQsHsDgQpEMGJtiCoAI4IYB2CIqaiONTcIhFCb1ayLXDoADmeOo1AYQA)

```
   async function titles(word) {
      const sentence = [];
      const api = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts";
      const data = await fetch(api);
      const response = await data.json();
      const titles = response.map(({ title }) => title);
      sentence.push(...titles);
      const people = sentence.filter((title) => title.indexOf(word) > -1);
      return people;
    }
```